# get VM IP address on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vmware, virtual-machine

I am running a Debian VMware virtual machine on Windows7. I am developing a Rails web app on the virtual machine, I would like to access the app (localhost:3000) from outside the vm, i.e from windows.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on how your virtual network adapters are setup between the guest and host. Assuming you have not changed anything, they will be bridged by default. In your VM from a terminal run:

```
ifconfig
```

This will give you the IPv4 address (generally a 10.x.x.x) of the virtual interface which you should be able to access from your Windows host. You should be able to put that into your browser on the host with the `:3000` port and access it.

If you have modified the network adapters, things may be different. For instance, setting it up as a NAT will give it an address on your physical network; i.e. 192.x.x.x, but accessing it the same. A host only netowork, would also most likely provide a 10.x.x.x address, but should also provide access.